Problem with visitors/day computation?
I noticed since a few weeks that the rate of visitors/day has dropped down in an irrealistic manner. It went from about 5000 visitors/day to 5.
Did something change in the way it is counted or is it just a bug ? 

It seems to be fixed by now!!!

Area 51 still looks broken however the network overview page seems to be working again (currently showing 4.5k/day).
